# Why LFSR stream code is not suitable for encryption?

Tags: encryption, lfsr

Why LFSR stream code is not suitable for encryption? Is there a special attack for LFSR?

Comment: Might be more suitable at https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: First google result - http://www.mat.uniroma3.it/scuola_orientamento/alumni/laureati/guarino/Thesis.pdf

Comment: Berlakamp-Massey algorithm;  [Breaking the 40 bit DVD CSS stream cipher](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/86510/18298), [Linear Feedback Shift Registers analysis](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/77302/18298)

Comment: @DanielW. It is more into [Cryptography.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/77302/linear-feedback-shift-registers-analysis/77303#77303), however, we have answers to cover that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has duped in crypto.